# @types/dialogflow package says "dialogflow provides its own type definitions" but it seems not

Tags: typescript, npm, dialogflow-es

I am using [dialogflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow) npm package, which is different from [actions-on-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) or [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) package.

The *dialogflow* package didn't have its own type definitions. Therefore, I have been using [@types/dialogflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dialogflow) package together.

Recently, the type definition package (@types/dialogflow) updated from [v0.11.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dialogflow/v/0.11.0) to [v4.0.4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dialogflow/v/4.0.4), which is the latest version now, and the package says that

> This is a stub types definition. dialogflow provides its own type
>   definitions, so you do not need this installed.

But the dialogflow npm package does not seem to give type definitions. The TS compiler keeps saying

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'dialogflow'. '....js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm install @types/dialogflow` if
>   it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'dialogflow';`ts(7016)

What's wrong with this type definition package?

Comment: what version of nodejs-dialogflow are you using ? the last one - 1.0.0 ?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- 0.9.1 and then 1.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, dialogflow hasn't published its types yet. There is no issue for that, they are not even listed on [this ticket](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/952) that tracks google APIs type definitions. (referenced from [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/issues/153))

[This PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/39717) which deprecated `@types/dialogflow` does not added any relevant link to show they were natively included.

I would add the fixed version of  `@types/dialogflow` on your package json in the meantime

> npm install @types/dialogflow@0.11.0

That version seems to be the last one prior to the deprecation

**Update**

Another option [according to this PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/39627) is to try importing this way

```js
import * as dialogflow from "dialogflow/protos/protos"
```

and verify the types on `dialogflow` - perhaps you might have to do some rework

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this can help but if I'm using a package which not have type definition I'm always use es5 import syntax like this

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
```

Let me know if you have any problem

Cheers.

Comment: The problem is that `@types/dialogflow@0.11.0` did provide type information but `@types/dialogflow@4.0.4` seems not to give any type information. `const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');` will make it compile, but there will be no type definition of `dialogflow`.